# SonataBlockBundle How to get Block's default settings inside controller

Tags: symfony, sonata

I have created a Block service extending BaseBlockService of sonataBlockBundle. And the following is configureSettings function where I have defined my defaults.

```
public function configureSettings(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'title' => 'My Block',
        'wrapper' => 'col-md-12',
        'content' => 'This is my block content',
        'template' => 'MyBlockBundle:Block:block.html.twig'
    ]);
}
```

In controller, I am able to get the block using `sonata.block.loader.service` `load`. When dumping the block, the settings is an empty array.

How can I get the default settings defined in the above function inside the controller. Is it possible?  If yes, how I can get this?